# OrientDB use result of subquery to search index

Tags: java, sql, orientdb

I am using OrientDb 2.1-rc4 as a document database. I have a `MyClass` class that gets updated very frequently by a multithreded application. To improve performance I removed the link from the `State` class to `MyClass`, and added a link and index from `MyClass` to `State.` In order to get all instances of `MyClass` I need to get a list of `State` rids and then query the index. This query gets my State rids.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(roles.views.states.@rid) 
FROM #12:1
```

returns

```
[["#14:0","#14:1"]]
```

This query finds the correct rids in the index.

```
SELECT FROM index:MyClass.state 
where key in [#14:0,#14:1]
```

When I put the two queries together.

```
SELECT FROM index:MWorkUnit.state 
where key in (SELECT DISTINCT(roles.views.states.@rid) FROM #12:1)
```

I get the following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery cannot be cast to java.util.List

How do I get OrientDB to treat my subquery as an rid list?

Edit:
This query works when not using the index.

```
SELECT FROM MWorkUnit 
where state IN (SELECT expand(roles.views.states).@rid FROM #12:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bug on query against indexes: sub queries are not correctly evaluated. Please could you open a new issue or that?

This workaround should work:

```
SELECT FROM index:MWorkUnit.state 
LET $list = (SELECT DISTINCT(roles.views.states.@rid) FROM #12:1) 
where key in $list
```